# Java : Digital Signature Verification Program

Tags: java, digital-signature, key-pair

I have created a program,
Where I have two actors.

1. AWS Lambda Function -> sender
2. REST API -> reciever

What I wanted was a mechanism where I can send a special digital signature based on public-private key and the same signature can be verified at the receivers' end.
Everything is working fine but my keys which are getting generated are very long, since I will be moving this to production and storing such long key is a risk. I was hoping if somehow I can shorten the encoded string it will be great.

1. public key is stored in property file in REST API module.
2. private key is stored with my AWS Lambda function's env variable which will call the REST API.

Program to generate Keys is as follows.

```
package org.example;

import java.security.*;
import java.util.Base64;

public class KeyPairGenerator {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {

        generateKeyPair();

    }

    public static void generateKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {


        java.security.KeyPairGenerator keyGen = java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        keyGen.initialize(2048, random);

        KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey priv = pair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey pub = pair.getPublic();

        printPublicKey(pub);
        printPrivateKey(priv);

    }

    private static void printPrivateKey(PrivateKey priv) {
        byte[] key = priv.getEncoded();
        System.out.println("Private Key:"+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key));

    }

    private static void printPublicKey(PublicKey pub) {

        byte[] key = pub.getEncoded();
        System.out.println("Public Key:"+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key));

    }
}
```

Output of the program i:e; the key which will be genrated for the actual actors to use are as follows.

```
"org.example.KeyPairGenerator
Public Key:MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAxVxVUL4r4Zufb6f61CROD90uxa3YuhwaNngZ0eQjtEzn/BxeDqUU3kH8S9FdP5qhFoJJB/LPhpB8jNZnDN4ClG4F+dfiJuTr4RJ2hW2E9o3NQk2kxcsxq4aY5SzKLMtm3+XBTLv+2gckkvgIxwVaQEuvETersWt1x8NqlhnYhAr/OkdcdOrRzg8V7vikp4GBenA+zb/MQD3DQMqMmceNidKQDISz2D4axICooborGz/V6PLOjGKCUHCsNUk9CFJ0geizJ1cuCZrSidnEtUC5IlMypaKU/6M1J/rtj3rQ09mvtOff0j0qK1R2KQHEwowk3jkvRavzLO9m4VALF/lyYwIDAQAB
Private Key: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

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If you look closely the keys are too long to be stored in any properties file.
Is there any way I can shorten the keys ?

Comment: Where exactly do you have an issue with storing these long keys in a properties file? Usually there is no such limit. Please [edit] your question to include any error message you get when storing (or reading) the properties files.

Comment: yes the issue is storing such long key, there's no error message that comes when storing such long values, its just that if there is any way which I can use to shorten the key it will be helpful. Long keys may not be entertained by my architects.

Comment: When there are no error message, how do you know it is an issue? What is the problem you have?

Comment: My pull request will not get apporved, as in the review comments I have been asked to shorten the key.

Comment: What "pull request" are you talked about and what "review comments" are you referring to? Keep in mind we can only read any information you provide in your question. When your co-workers are mentioning any issues with the key then you have to ask them, what the problem is. You can generate a RSA key with keysize 1024 instead of 2048, but this still will create a "long" key.